# How to provide implementation specialization with a specific set of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

```
template<typename T,int N>
class Matrix;

template<typename T, 0>
class Matrix{
    T val;
};

template<typename T, 1>
class Matrix{
    T* elem;
    int sz;
};
```

I get syntax errors.

Code from Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ programming language Ch25.3.1.1 Implementation Specialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

```
template<typename T,int N>
class Matrix;

template<typename T>
class Matrix<T, 0>{
    T val;
};

template<typename T>
class Matrix<T, 1>{
    T* elem;
    int sz;
};
```